# Google Authenticator Scratch Codes

Tags: android, security, google-authenticator

I've done some googling on this but can't seem to find if this is possible.

I'm looking to implement Google Authenticator on my website and it seems fairly easy to generate a nice QRCode for the user to scan, or a secret key to manually input.  What I want to know is if it's possible to also grab the emergency scratch codes?

I see Google has a PAM module which can do this and gives the emergency codes when you generate your first one, but it seems the QRCode doesn't contain this data, where can I get it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, it seems that the emergency codes are randomly generated by Google and stored, so presumably I can do that myself in my application.